# orderby and order filter in get_posts or WP_query function in wordpress not working

Tags: wp-query, get-posts, order

I have function in wordpress plugin which queries the posts using get_posts($array). But I wanted this to orderby post_modified field of the posts table in DESCENDING order, for which I have this code below:

```
    $arrProducts = get_the_terms($intPostId, 'products');

    if (is_array($arrProducts) && count($arrProducts)) {
        foreach ($arrProducts as $intKey => $arrProductsObj) {
            $intTermId = $arrProductsObj->term_id;
            $strSlug = $arrProductsObj->slug;
            $strName = $arrProductsObj->name;
            $children = get_term_children($intTermId, 'products'); // get children
            if(sizeof($children)==0)
            {
                array_push($arrTermId, $intTermId);
                array_push($arrTermName, $strName);
                array_push($arrTermSlug, $strSlug);
            }

        }
    }

    $intCTermId = "";
    $arrCTermId = array();
    $arrCTermName = array();
    $arrCTermSlug = array();
    $arrCProducts = get_the_terms($intPostId, 'kiacategory');
         /* echo "<pre>";
  print_r($arrCProducts);exit(); */ 
    if (is_array($arrCProducts) && count($arrCProducts)) {   
        foreach ($arrCProducts as $intCKey => $arrCProductsObj) {
            $intCTermId = $arrCProductsObj->term_id;
            $strCSlug = $arrCProductsObj->slug;
            $strCName = $arrCProductsObj->name;
            $children = get_term_children($intCTermId, 'kiacategory'); // get children
            if(sizeof($children)==0)
            {
                array_push($arrCTermId, $intCTermId);
               array_push($arrCTermName, $strCName);
               array_push($arrCTermSlug, $strCSlug);
            }

        }
    }


$arrPostDtls = get_posts(array(
                'post_type' => 'kiaarticles',
                'posts_per_page' => -1, 
                'post_status' => array('publish', 'pending', 'trash','draft','auto-draft') ,
    'orderby' => 'post_modified',
    'order'  => 'DESC',
                'tax_query' => array(
                    'relation' => 'AND',
                    array(
                        'taxonomy' => 'products',
                        'field' => 'slug',
                        'terms' => $arrTermSlug,
                        'operator' => 'IN'
                    ),
                    array(
                        'taxonomy' => 'kiacategory',
                        'field' => 'slug',
                        'terms' => $arrCTermSlug,
                        'operator' => 'IN'
                    )
                )     
                ));
```

Here, I did implemented the orderby or order clauses to get it sorted accordingly, but it doesnt work. Please suggest or help me to get the sorting as I am willing to.

**UPDATE**
To get the things other way, I used the WP_query method to get the posts. for which I implemented below code:

```
$arrPostDtls = new WP_query(array(
        'post_type' => 'kiaarticles',
        'posts_per_page' => -1, //unlikely high
        'post_status' => array('publish', 'pending', 'trash','draft','auto-draft'),
        'orderby' => 'modified',
        'tax_query' => array(
            'relation' => 'AND',
            array(
                'taxonomy' => 'products',
                'field' => 'slug',
                'terms' => $arrTermSlug,
                'operator' => 'IN'
            ),
            array(
                'taxonomy' => 'kiacategory',
                'field' => 'slug',
                'terms' => $arrCTermSlug,
                'operator' => 'IN'
            )
        )
        ));

$strData = '<table id="id_'.$intPostId.'" class="table table-striped table-bordered" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th>Title</th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tfoot>
                    <tr>
                        <th>Title</th>                
                    </tr>
                </tfoot><tbody>';
             foreach ($arrPostDtls->posts as $arrPostDtlsVal) {

                $intResultpostId = $arrPostDtlsVal->ID;
                $strPostLink = get_permalink($intResultpostId);
                $strPostTitle = $arrPostDtlsVal->post_title;
                $strData.='<tr><td><a href = "' . $strPostLink . '">' . $strPostTitle . '</a></td></tr>';

            }
            $strData .='</tbody>
            </table>';
```

From this I recieved the result which also contains the SQL query, and executing the SQL query in PHPmyadmin, I found the exepected result, but when i iterated the "$arrPostDtls->posts", it still gives me the old results.. Please suggest what is wrong here..

Comment: are you getting the correct results in the wrong order or are the results also wrong?

Comment: I am getting results in a alphabetic order of post_title, which I dont see applied anywhere in the code above, and hence it looks like my orderby post_modified is not working at all

Comment: it should be just `'modified'` not `'post_modified'`. Can also skip `'order'` since it's `'DESC'` by default.

Comment: @inarilo I tried that as well, but it didnt work either.

Comment: uh just realised you are not assigning your `get_posts` result to anything. you are probably just printing out the results of the default query, not yours.

Comment: @inarilo nothing like that either, by bad though, as I didnt mentioned in code snippet. It is being assigned to a variable and the foreach loop is being iterared around the variable "$arrPostDtls", i have updated by question with it now, thanks, but sorry for confusion

Comment: @inarilo I have updated my question for new way to get the result, this time I got little closer but still not done... can you help

Comment: could be a caching problem, but then again maybe not if it's printing the query. can't see what the problem might be. add the code for your loop.

Comment: @inarilo I have added the loop as well, please have a look

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found my problem on the UI side (thanks to @CBroe) where by ajax response was being exposed to a jQuery library `DataTable()`, whose default ordering was sorting in alphabetical order. I set the ordering parameter to false as:

```
$("#someid").DataTable({"ordering":false});
```

And My results were displayed as I was willing to